# help needed for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm to determine the solution for $$te^{tx}x'+xe^{tx}+3t^2=0$$

I've tried:

$te^{tx}dx+(xe^{tx}+3t^2)dt=0$

$\Rightarrow e^{tx}+t^3+(xe^{tx})dt=0$

I'm confused about $(xe^{tx})dt$ this part. I'm guessing this: $$ (e^{tx})'=x'xe^{tx} \to xe^{tx}=\frac{(e^{tx})'}{x'}$$ is supposed to be use? Is this right?

But then how do I calculate $\frac{(e^{tx})'}{x'}dt$?

Comment: Hint: $$(e^{tx})'.$$

Comment: Wouldn't $\frac{d}{dt} e^{t x}$ be equal to $(x+t x') e^{t x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dt} (e^{tx}) &=& (x+tx') e^{tx}\\
\frac{d}{dt} (e^{tx}) + 3t^2 &=& 0\\
\frac{d}{dt} (e^{tx}) &=& - 3t^2\\
e^{tx} &=& -t^3 + C\\
tx &=& \ln ( C - t^3)\\
x &=& \frac{1}{t} \ln ( C - t^3)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: thanks. I see what I did wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

$te^{tx}dx+(xe^{tx}+3t^2)dt=0$ is of the form $Mdx+Ndt=0$ and $\partial M/\partial t=\partial N/\partial x$ which implies the ODE is exact one.

On integration term by term, $e^{tx}+t^3=c$ is the solution.

> *Rule*-Ignore the terms from $\int Ndt$ which already occured in $\int Mdx$.